# Integration of densities

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Given a measure space $X$, positive measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $X$, and respectively $\mu$- and $\nu$-integrable functions $g$ and $h$, such that for every measurable set $E$,
$$\int_E g~d\mu=\int_E h~d\nu,$$

I'm trying to come up with the class of (complex) measurable functions $f$ that satisfy
$$\int_X fg~d\mu=\int_X fh~d\nu.$$

I was able to show that this class includes those functions $f$, such  that $fg$ is $\mu$-integrable and $fh$ is $\nu$-integrable, resp., by the dominated convergence theorem, but I wasn't able to figure out whether $\mu$-integrability of $fg$ implied $\nu$-integrability of $fh$, or not. Does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define, for every measurable set $E$, 
$$ \beta(E)=\int_E g~d\mu$$ and $$ \gamma(E)= \int_E h~d\nu$$ 
It is immediate that $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are (complex) measures and $\beta=\gamma$.

For any function $f$, $f$ is $\beta$-integrable iff $f$ is $\gamma$-integrable, and for $f$  $\beta$-integrable (and so $\gamma$-integrable), we have

$$\int_E f g~d\mu= \int_X f ~d\beta = \int_X f ~d\gamma = \int_E f h~d\nu$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess I'll just comment that (I think?) you could also use the same idea with the total variations of $\beta$ or $\gamma$, if integration w.r.t. complex measures wasn't familiar territory.

Comment: @user303019 , Yes, you could use the same idea with the total variation $\beta$ and $\gamma$. It would make the proof a few lines longer.